# Use each element of the array in a string to form standardized sentences

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, range, template-literals

I want to create an array that is tied to a standardized sentence. I understand how to create an array to list a range of numbers, however, how can I add the elements of the array to a sentence?

For example, I want to create **25 sentences**, all with different numbers in them from my array.

Sentence template:

```
This is number: (a number from the array), okay?
```

And the sentences would be like:

```
This is number **1**, okay?
This is number **2**, okay?
This is number **3**, okay?
...
This is number **25**, okay?
```

Here is my current array code:

```js
function range(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}
var result = range(1, 25); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating the specific `range(...)`, use [**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and 
 [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to easily generate standardized sentences from the particular `num`:

```js
function range(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

const sentences = range(1, 25).map(num => `This is number ${num}, okay?`);
console.log(sentences);
```